# TypeScript 3.1.6 Angular 7 Rxjs6 Using catchError shows error in editor but the code runs correctly

Tags: angular, angular7, rxjs6, typescript3.0

I am trying to return a custom error from a data service in the event of and error.

```
public getRoles(): Observable<Array<Role> | CustomError> {

    return this.http.get(this.urlService.getRoles)
        .pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                    let roles = new Array<Role>();
                    res.Result.forEach(item => {
                        roles.push(new Role().fromItem(item));
                    });

                    return roles;
                }
            ),
            catchError(err => {
                let customError = new CustomError();
                customError.errorNumber = err.status;
                customError.message = err.message;
                return throwError(customError);
            })
        );
}
```

The code above acutally runs as i expect it should, but the text editor indicates the following error:

(TS) Type 'Observable<{} | Role[]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableRole[] | CustomError>'.

Type '{} | Role[]' is not assignable to type 'Role[] | CustomError'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Role[] | CustomError'.

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'CustomError'.

Property 'errorNumber' is missing in type '{}'

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to resolve the problem?

It turns out that this is not the only place in the code where I am having an issue with catchError. I have a simple interceptor that will log http errors to the console. (I was experimenting on how to use interceptors).

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(`ErrorInterceptor - ${req.url}`);

    return next.handle(req)
        .pipe(catchError(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return throwError(err);
        }));
}
```

With this block of code I am getting a very similar set of messages. Am I using catchError and throwError correctly?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What kind of editor are you using? What does the console with ng serve tells you? Does ng serve --prod pass ?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017. ng serve --prod does pass

Comment: The generic type of an Observable is the type of the *events* it emits. Your only emit events of type Array<Role>. CustomError is the type of the error, not the type of the event. You observable should just be declared as Observable<Array<Role>>. See https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError: its return type is Observable<never>, because it never emits anything.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I understand what you are saying, but can you offer a suggestion on how to fix what I am trying to do?

Comment: Your observable should just be declared as Observable<Array<Role>>.

Comment: I read an article that did a very good job of discussing error handling and observables here: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/  However, even after rewriting my code to do what is explained in this article, I still get what looks like errors in the text editor. The code does function correctly.

Answer (score -1):

My be, you need to import the throwError class? :

```
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
```